# What is wrong with this regex in my rule redirect? (web.config)

Tags: regex, web-config

This is a Azure WebApp web.config question.
I want to redirect all non-HTTPS requests to same url but with HTTPS, basically replacing the HTTP with HTTPS.
But not if the url containst following string: "/config/add_new_user?login=xxx&w=1".

This is my  block in the  section in web-config.

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(\/config\/add_new_user\?login=license_wizard\&w=1)" negate="true" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="public/redirect.html" />
</rule>
```

But i get error 500.19 - Configuration file is not well-formed XML

I used https://regex101.com/#javascript to work out the regex and tested with different urls. It seams to work out, the expression hits on the text.
So the negate="true" should reverse the statement, so only urls without the given string is matched and thus rewritten.

Oh by the way, the web.config xml seams to be ok, because when i change the regex back to the original then web-site works.

So this works:

```
<match url="(.*)" />
```

and this does not:

```
<match url="(\/config\/add_new_user\?login=license_wizard\&w=1)" negate="true" />
```

Comment: I don't think `&` needs escaping, or is a valid escape sequence in that context, try `(\/config\/add_new_user\?login=license_wizard&w=1)`

Comment: I tried both escaped and without, same result :/ But I think you're right about & not needing to be escaped.

Comment: You should probably also be using the PCRE flavor instead of Javascript https://regex101.com/#pcre

Comment: Maybe `&` should be `&amp;` as it's in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` must be encoded as `&amp;` in XML files.

```
<match url="(\/config\/add_new_user\?login=license_wizard\&amp;w=1)" negate="true" />
```

Comment: You're right, thanks!
Though the & should not be escaped in the example you have posted.